# Slow query, looking on pointers how to optimize it

Tags: php, sql, database, optimization

I have a query that takes about 9 seconds. It makes my website very slow. Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to optimize it for better performance. Don't judge the syntax, it's pretty ugly :$

```
SELECT songs.id, count(votes.song_id) AS votes
    FROM songs, songs_genre, votes 
    WHERE votes.song_id=songs.id 
        AND songs_genre.genre_id IN ('$genre_ids') 
        AND songs.id=songs_genre.song_id 
        AND votes.date<=DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL + 1 DAY) 
        AND votes.date>=DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 3 MONTH) 
    GROUP BY votes.song_id
    ORDER BY votes DESC limit 36
```

Comment: add EXPLAIN to the query check the db is indexed properly

Comment: it's  reasonable to guess that the following should be indexed: songs.id,votes.song_id,songs_genre.genre_id,songs_genre.song_id,votes.date,votes(what ever table that is)

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, the table votes that has half a million entries wasn't indexed. There was the problem. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

The query looks good, I would say that only thing that would improve the performance offhand is proper indexing on votes or songs id.

Comment: Ahh, didn't see your last comment. It was indexing. ;)